# Group Collection by multiple column - Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections

So, i have this collection in laravel :

```
$collection = [
 {OC: "3.01", C: "922.76", D: "0"},
 {OC: "3.01", C: "0", D: "78004027.00"},
 {OC: "3.02", C: "0", D: "116442.60"},
 {OC: "3.03", C: "0", D: "833.83"},
 {OC: "3.04", C: "772.50", D: "0"},
 {OC: "3.04", C: "0", D: "3345.50"}
];
```

i need to group so i have one OC of a kind, each one can have one or two records (one for C != 0 and one for D != 0), in this case for example the expected result is:

```
$collection = [
 {OC: "3.01", C: "922.76", D: "78004027.00"},
 {OC: "3.02", C: "0", D: "116442.60"},
 {OC: "3.03", C: "0", D: "833.83"},
 {OC: "3.04", C: "772.50", "3345.50"},
];
```

whats the most effective way i can do it? can someone please shed a light, i tried using ->groupBy but i can only group by OC and its not solving my problem

much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works too!

```
   $results = $collection->groupBy('OC')->map(function($array){

        $result = [];

        foreach($array[0] as $key => $arr){
          $result += [$key => $array->max($key)];
        }
        return $result;

    })->values();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` function... something like: (Not tested)

If your data is a collection:

```
$modified = $collection->reduce(function ($carry, $item) {
    if(empty($carry[$item->OC])){ //Not on the final array
       //Create it
       $carry[$item->OC] = $item;
    } else { //Exists, then update C/D with maximum value
       $carry[$item->OC]->C = max($carry[$item->OC]->C, $item->C); 
       $carry[$item->OC]->D = max($carry[$item->OC]->D, $item->D); 
    } 

    return $carry;
}, [])->values();
```

Or if your data is an array:

```
$modified = array_values($collection, array_reduce(function ($carry, $item) {
    if(empty($carry[$item->OC])){ //Not on the final array
       //Create it
       $carry[$item->OC] = $item;
    } else { //Exists, then update C/D with maximum value
       $carry[$item->OC]->C = max($carry[$item->OC]->C, $item->C); 
       $carry[$item->OC]->D = max($carry[$item->OC]->D, $item->D); 
    } 

    return $carry;
}, []));
```

Then you have your values in `$modified` var.

Comment: thanks, worked like a charm, just needed to remove the ' ,[]) ->values(); '
maybe due to laravel version, but its working